# Ruby Mechanize gem not following meta refresh

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I have a Ruby 2.2 automation script that uses Mechanize to log in to Google Payments. When I try to access the url Mechanize stops on the meta refresh. The content of the page is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Redirecting...</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var url = 'https:\/\/accounts.google.com\/ServiceLogin?
         service\x3dbilling\x26passive\x3d1209600\x26continue\x3dhttps:\/\/payments.google.com\/
         payments\/home%23__HASH__\x26followup\x3dhttps:\/\/payments.google.com\/payments\/
         home'; var fragment = ''; if (self.document.location.hash) {fragment = self.document.
         location.hash.replace(/^#/,'');}url = url.replace(new RegExp("__HASH__", 'g'), 
         encodeURIComponent(fragment));window.location.assign(url);
    </script><noscript><meta 
http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url='https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?
 service&#61;billing&amp;passive&#61;1209600&amp;continue&#61;https://payments.google.com
 /payments/home&amp;followup&#61;https://payments.google.com/payments/home'"></meta>
</noscript></head>

<body></body>
</html>
```

Here is the part of my script to get to the login screen:

```
@agent = Mechanize.new  
@agent.follow_meta_refresh = true  
page = @agent.get("http://payments.google.com/payments/home")  
puts page.content
```

The page.content at the end only shows the above html, the meta refresh is not followed. Any suggestions on how I can follow that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Idempotence I think you had the right idea, but I [reformatted](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=html+beautify&ia=answer&atb=v35-3a_) it myself, because that was quicker than proofreading.

Comment: You actually can't have line breaks in the url like that, it breaks the script.

Comment: @pguardiario Someone thought it would be clever to format my original post of the returned values. The original url does not contain line breaks.

Comment: Yes that's what I figured :) @jpaugh got a bit overzealous.

Comment: @ analyticsPierce, @pguardiario My apologies! I used an automated tool to reformat it, but if it's broken please revert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the script isn't really reformatted like that:

```
url = page.body[/url = '(.*?)'/, 1]
page = @agent.get url
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. I think the url being retrieved is invalid or needs to be converted. Any suggestions? Here is the url value gets pulled out: https:\/\/accounts.google.com\/ServiceLogin?service\x3dbilling\x26passive\x3d1209600\x26continue\x3dhttps:\/\/payments.google.com\/payments\/home%23__HASH__\x26followup\x3dhttps:\/\/payments.google.com\/payments\/home

Comment: The url being returned had extra backslahes that made it invalid. I replaced the '\/' with '/' and the url worked just fine.